# Is a SQLITE String with multiple queries synchronous in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, asynchronous

i know that if you make multiple queries in Android they are asynchronous .

But i wonder if multiple queries in one String are still asynchronous ?

E.g.:

```
"CREATE TABLE bar (num); INSERT INTO bar VALUES (1)"
```

instead of:

```
 1st Query: CREATE TABLE bar (num);
 2nd Query: INSERT INTO bar VALUES (1)
 This can cause an error because the table might not be created yet.
```

Comment: This will cause an error because the API does not support it. What makes you assume that the API is asynchronous?

Comment: Oh ok, thanks :) i thought i can use multiple statements for it. So i need to use html5sql then.